# Callback for MVVM binding in Kendo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I get a flash of unstyled content when I initially load the page, it seems until Kendo.bind(element, viewModel) takes time to process the HTML to scan, parse, manipulate, etc.

It would be nice if the [kendo object](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo) had page lifecycle events so I can subscribe to it for example, but it doesn't seem like there's something for that. Is there a way I can hide the container element or load a progress bar, then fade in when Kendo is done changing the page? Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure what you're seeing is cause by Kendo UI? a demo/code to reproduce would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the 'scan, parse, manipulate' slow down that you mentioned is in fact until your page loads the scripts and actually reaches the code that performs the actual binding.

```
kendo.bind(container, viewModel)
```

So you can initially display some kind of loading animation icon and just before kendo.bind you should hide it.

Comment: That helped thx! The scripts were loaded at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

<div id="myViewModelId" data-bind="visible: getIsSectionVisible" style="display: none">

</div>

On your viewModel, getIsSectionVisible would return false till you are ready and then true when you want the section visible.